Emails from wordpress@mydomain.com fail authentication when a new user is set up
I set up a wordpress site with custom email.  Setup SPF, DKIM and DMARC on my DNS and the emails such as charlie@my-domain.com go through fine.
When I create a new user on the site, that user gets an notifications from wordpress@my-domain.com but those emails arrive in the users inbox but with a warning that the email has failed authentication and maybe spoofed.
How can I authenticate these emails?

How are you sending the emails? Through a server that's authorised to by SPF, that will add the DKIM signature? Using a third party service?

Do you have an example of an email with the added warnings? Look at the message headers and hopefully you'll get some diagnostics from the mail server that added the warning what the problem was - whether it was SPF, DKIM, etc.

You'll need to use an SMTP plugin to send your emails through your domain's mailserver instead of using the PHP mail() function (which is how WP sends them by default).
